# use dplyr's summarise_each to return one row per function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using dplyr's summarise_each to apply a function to multiple columns of data.  One thing that's nice is that you can apply multiple functions at once.  Thing is, it's annoying that the output is a dataframe with a single row.  It seems like it should return as many rows as functions, with as many columns as columns that were summarised.

```
library(dplyr)  
default <- 
  iris %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min, max), matches("Petal"))
```

this returns

```
> default
  Petal.Length_min Petal.Width_min Petal.Length_max Petal.Width_max
1                1             0.1              6.9             2.5
```

I'd prefer something like

```
library(reshape2)
desired <- 
  iris %>% 
  select(matches("Petal")) %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarize(min=min(value),max=max(value)) %>%
  t()
```

which returns something close (not a dataframe, but you all get the idea)

```
> desired
         [,1]           [,2]         
variable "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
min      "1.0"          "0.1"        
max      "6.9"          "2.5"
```

is there an option in summarise_each to do this?  If not, Hadley, would you mind adding it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can achieve a similar output combining the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages.
Something along these lines can help

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

iris %>%
  select(matches("Petal")) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(min, max)) %>%
  gather(variable, value) %>%
  separate(variable, c("var", "stat"), sep = "\\_") %>%
  spread(var, value)
##   stat Petal.Length Petal.Width
## 1  max          6.9         2.5
## 2  min          1.0         0.1
```

Comment: cool, and a little bit shorter (with default values) `gather %>% separate(key, c("key","stat"), sep = "_") %>% spread(key, value)`

Comment: @ckluss Nice, thanks. Feel free to edit the answer to update it.

Comment: Very nice.  Gives me a reason to finally dive into tidyr.  Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks @dickoa. If you have column names with multiple underscores, you can use this regex: `sep = "_(?=[^_]*$)"`. It will match only the last underscore to split the columns.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge there's no such argument. Anyhow, here's a workaround that outputs tidy data, I think that would be even better than having as many rows as functions and as many columns as summarised columns. (note that `add_rownames` requires [dplyr 0.4.0](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/01/09/dplyr-0-4-0/))

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")

iris %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(min, max, mean, median), matches("Petal")) %>%
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  add_rownames %>%
  separate(rowname, into = c("feature", "fun"), sep = "_")
```

returns:

```
       feature    fun       V1
1 Petal.Length    min 1.000000
2  Petal.Width    min 0.100000
3 Petal.Length    max 6.900000
4  Petal.Width    max 2.500000
5 Petal.Length   mean 3.758000
6  Petal.Width   mean 1.199333
7 Petal.Length median 4.350000
8  Petal.Width median 1.300000
```

Comment: I could see this format being useful in many situations.  thanks!

Comment: Small pedantic note: `add_rownames()` is now deprecated and the suggestion is to use  `tibble::rownames_to_column()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `purrr::map_df` (really `map_dfc` to simplify back to a data.frame with `bind_cols` though `map_df` is fine for now) with a function that makes a vector of results of each function, i.e.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% select(contains('Petal')) %>% 
    map_dfc(~c(min(.x), max(.x))) %>% 
    mutate(stat = c('min', 'max'))    # to add column of function names

#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Petal.Length Petal.Width  stat
#>          <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>
#> 1          1.0         0.1   min
#> 2          6.9         2.5   max
```

Comment: change `dmap` -> `map_df` for newer version of `purrr`, per [tidyverse news](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/news/#purrr-and-dplyr)